# Python extracting data from HTML using split

Tags: python, html-parsing

A certain page retrieved from a URL, has the following syntax :

```
<p>
    <strong>Name:</strong> Pasan <br/>
    <strong>Surname: </strong> Wijesingher <br/>                    
    <strong>Former/AKA Name:</strong> No Former/AKA Name <br/>                    
    <strong>Gender:</strong> Male <br/>
    <strong>Language Fluency:</strong> ENGLISH <br/>                    
</p>
```

I want to extract the data in Name, Surname etc. (I have to repeat this task for many pages)

For that I tried using the following code:

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.my.lk/details.aspx?view=1&id=%2031'
source = urllib2.urlopen(url)

start = '<p><strong>Given Name:</strong>'
end = '<strong>Surname'
givenName=(source.read().split(start))[1].split(end)[0]

start = 'Surname: </strong>'
end = 'Former/AKA Name'
surname=(source.read().split(start))[1].split(end)[0]

print(givenName)
print(surname)
```

When I'm calling the source.read.split method only one time it works fine. But when I use it twice it gives a list index out of range error.

Can someone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for parsing the HTML string.

Here is some code you might try,
It is using BeautifulSoup (to get the text made by the html code), then parses the string for extracting the data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

dic = {}
data = \
"""
    <p>
        <strong>Name:</strong> Pasan <br/>
        <strong>Surname: </strong> Wijesingher <br/>                    
        <strong>Former/AKA Name:</strong> No Former/AKA Name <br/>                    
        <strong>Gender:</strong> Male <br/>
        <strong>Language Fluency:</strong> ENGLISH <br/>                    
    </p>
"""

soup = bs(data)
# Get the text on the html through BeautifulSoup
text = soup.get_text()

# parsing the text
lines = text.splitlines()
for line in lines:
    # check if line has ':', if it doesn't, move to the next line
    if line.find(':') == -1: 
        continue    
    # split the string at ':'
    parts = line.split(':')

    # You can add more tests here like
    # if len(parts) != 2:
    #     continue

    # stripping whitespace
    for i in range(len(parts)):
        parts[i] = parts[i].strip()    
    # adding the vaules to a dictionary
    dic[parts[0]] = parts[1]
    # printing the data after processing
    print '%16s %20s' % (parts[0],parts[1])
```

A tip:
If you are going to use BeautifulSoup to parse HTML,
You should have certain attributes like `class=input` or `id=10`, That is, you keep all tags of the same type to be the same id or class.

---

**Update**
Well for your comment, see the code below
It applies the tip above, making life (and coding) a lot easier

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

c_addr = []
id_addr = []
data = \
"""
<h2>Primary Location</h2>
<div class="address" id="10">
    <p>
       No. 4<br>
       Private Drive,<br>
       Sri Lanka&nbsp;ON&nbsp;&nbsp;K7L LK <br>
"""
soup = bs(data)

for i in soup.find_all('div'):
    # get data using "class" attribute
    addr = ""
    if i.get("class")[0] == u'address': # unicode string
        text = i.get_text()
        for line in text.splitlines(): # line-wise
            line = line.strip() # remove whitespace
            addr += line # add to address string
        c_addr.append(addr)

    # get data using "id" attribute
    addr = ""
    if int(i.get("id")) == 10: # integer
        text = i.get_text()
        # same processing as above
        for line in text.splitlines():
            line = line.strip()
            addr += line
        id_addr.append(addr)

print "id_addr"
print id_addr
print "c_addr"
print c_addr
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also have a section as
  <h2>Primary Location</h2>
  <div class="detail">
      <p>No, 4<br />Private Drive, <br />Sri Lanka&nbsp;ON&nbsp;&nbsp;K7L LK
                    <br />

From which I 'd like to extract the address. Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 5):

You are calling read() twice. That is the problem. Instead of doing that you want to call read once, store the data in a variable, and use that variable where you were calling read(). Something like this:

```
fetched_data = source.read()
```

Then later...

```
givenName=(fetched_data.split(start))[1].split(end)[0]
```

and...

```
surname=(fetched_data.split(start))[1].split(end)[0]
```

That should work. The reason your code didn't work is because the read() method is reading the content the first time, but after it gets done reading it is looking at the end of the content. The next time you call read() it has no more content remaining and throws an exception.

Check out the docs for [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) and [methods on file objects](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be quick, regexes are more useful for this kind of task. It can be a harsh learning curve at first but regexes will save your butt one day.

Try this code:

```
# read the whole document into memory
full_source = source.read()  

NAME_RE = re.compile('Name:.+?>(.*?)<')
SURNAME_RE = re.compile('Surname:.+?>(.*?)<')

name = NAME_RE.search(full_source, re.MULTILINE).group(1).strip()
surname = SURNAME_RE.search(full_source, re.MULTILINE).group(1).strip()
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) for more info on how to use regexes in python.

A more comprehensive solution would involve parsing the HTML (using a lib like BeautifulSoup), but that can be overkill depending on your particular application.

Comment: For this *specific* text, this will work. Note that in general, it is *not* a good idea to use regular expressions to parse HTML. It is much  more idiomatic (and much easier) to use an HTML parser such as BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Truth. Again, it depends on the situation. For a one-off parsing of text for data-mining regexes are perfectly fine. For library code or anything that goes into production you need a more robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTQL:

```
page="""
<p>
    <strong>Name:</strong> Pasan <br/>
    <strong>Surname: </strong> Wijesingher <br/>                    
    <strong>Former/AKA Name:</strong> No Former/AKA Name <br/>                    
    <strong>Gender:</strong> Male <br/>
    <strong>Language Fluency:</strong> ENGLISH <br/>                    
</p>
"""

import htql
print(htql.query(page, "<p>.<strong> {a=:tx; b=:xx} "))

# [('Name:', ' Pasan '), 
#  ('Surname: ', ' Wijesingher '), 
#  ('Former/AKA Name:', ' No Former/AKA Name '), 
#  ('Gender:', ' Male '), 
#  ('Language Fluency:', ' ENGLISH ')
# ]
```